# read multiple files and save to xls in columns (pypdf2 and xlsxwriterr

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pypdf, xmlwriter

I need to take a directory with multiple PDFs and structure it into an xls

but I didn't understand how to make a list in the directory save the data in xls

```
enter import PyPDF2
    import xlsxwriter
#---------------------Input file-----------------------------------#
pdf_file = open('arquivo_file','rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
doc = read_pdf.getOutlines
page_content = page.extractText()
text = page_content.replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", " ").replace("  ", "")
content = page_content.split("\n")
data = content[0]
worksheet.write(1, 1, data)
workbook.close() here
```

Comment: Please write your logic in plane English first, as steps you need to perform. Then google for each step. Often you may be amazed at the fact that your question was not necessary to ask on SO, had you broken it down into smaller steps and looked up answers for them instead.

Comment: read multiple files: means read a single file first. Then read those files in a loop.

Comment: save to xls in columns: search which libraries you could use in python to save to an excel file. If you are using [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/), well and good. But did you check what alternatives you have? Did you try `openpyxl`? Or [`pandas`](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-combine-python-pandas-xlsxwriter-8edd25678a6f)?

Comment: *"I need to take a directory with multiple PDFs"*: So you need a list of those PDF files in a directory. Did you try different search queries on google? Try this: **"get a list of files in a directory in python"**.

Comment: As a hint: you would need either `import os; os.listdir(DIRPATH)` or `import glob; glob.glob(DIRPATH)`.

Comment: So, create functions `read_pdf_file(filename)`, `write_excel_file(filename)`. Then loop over your `filenames = os.listdir(DIRPATH)` and successively call `read_pdf_file` and `write_excel_file`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically your code would resemble something like this.

```py
import os
import glob

DIRPATH = "/path/to/your/pdf/directory"

# Get list of files with extension .pdf in a given directory
pdf_filepaths = glob.glob(os.path.join(DIRPATH, '*.pdf'))

# Loop over the pdf file-paths
# For each pdf-file:
#   1. read each pdf file
#   2. process the content you read (optional)
#   3. save the processed content to excel file
for i, pdf_filepath in enumerate(pdf_filepaths):
    content = read_pdf_file(pdf_filepath)
    content = process_data(content)
    write_excel_file(filename='out_{i}.xlsx', content=content)
```

Here I assumed you would have wrapped your reading, processing and writing logic in three functions:

```py
def read_pdf_file(filepath):
   # your pdf reading logic goes here
   ...

   return content

def process_data(content):
   # your post-reading data-processing logic goes here
   ...

   return content

def write_excel_file(filepath, content):
   # your logic for writing to excel-file goes here
   ...
```